# Hiding the image not found cross mark using .htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, hide

So this page on my website has a large collections of icons. A large number of these icon images have been removed due to which "the cross mark" which is shown when an image is not found is displayed everywhere.

I was searching for a way to do this via .htaccess and tried a few things which did not work, unfortunately.

Firefox does not show any indication that an image is missing, IE and Chrome do.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.
Regards,
Vinith Almeida

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!-f` means "isn't a real file", `!-d` means "isn't a directory" and `!-l` means "isn't a symlink":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp)$ /images/empty.gif [L]
```

Where `/images/empty.gif` is any picture of your choice (eg. a 1x1 pixel transparent/white gif)

***Note**: In most cases you can let out the `!-l` part (it's only relevant if you use symlinks - if you don't know, then you most likely don't use symlinks).*

Comment: Thanks a lot, works just the way I wanted it to. If I write the above in the form of a pseudocode would this be right ? 'if there is no file, if there is no directory, then show the image empty.gif'

Comment: @vinith98 If my answer helped you answer your question, feel free to accept it. If you're unaware of how, you can read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).